# Unable to shutdown & reboot ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, reboot

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and I'm not able to shut down or reboot my laptop. After pressing the reboot/shutdown button it just shows the purple screen & 5 dots. I'm not able to understand where the problem is.

Comment: So can you turn it on?

Comment: yeah there is no issue in turning on the system

Comment: What do you get when you execute `sudo poweroff` and `sudo reboot` on a terminal?

Comment: Or `sudo shutdown -P now`

Comment: i didn't try that, i'm trying to shutdown or reboot from the gui

Comment: after executing sudo poweroff the same problem is persisting

Comment: What about my suggestion, `sudo shutdown -P now`?

Comment: i tried it.this also didnt work, same problem is happening

Comment: So how do you shut it down?

Comment: i'm hibernating it

Comment: [Try this solution][1] if you have the Plank dock installed.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/558975/ubuntu-hanging-on-shutdown-reboot/562747#562747

Answer (score 1):

Does any of the below work?

```
sudo shutdown -r now
sudo shutdown -H now
sudo shutdown -P now

sudo shutdown -rv now
```

will verbose you while trying a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

try this one 1st reset unity & ubuntu desktop

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
$ sudo apt-get install unity
$ setsid unity
```

if this didnt work

```
$ gksu "gedit /etc/default/grub"
```

change this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

by this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

save then update grub by typ

```
$ sudo grub-update
```

Comment: both the solutions didnt work

Comment: upgrade it again
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo shutdown -r

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, and finally after many, many hours of searching and experimenting I think I have a solution at least for the class of netbooks/laptops supporting UEFI boot mode (my laptop is ACER TravelMate B115):

In BIOS, under Boot, change **Boot Mode to UEFI** (after installing Ubuntu in Legacy mode).

This solution does not  not require changing grub configuration file *`/etc/default/grub`* (by adding `ACPI=off` and/or `ACPI=force` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`), which was questionable in 1st place anyway.

In my investigation I tried:

- installing Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS from scratch
- updating Ubuntu to use latest
- changing grub parameters
- upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04
- upgrading BIOS to the latest for TravelMate B115 (V122 to V126)
- analysing the syslog